# Trying to bend an object

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to bend an object using "simple deform", the deformation was all messed up even if following exact steps as seen on youtube. I've made a video in which you can see the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHP2oEHG9Ng&t

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). Can you please add some images of the shape you're going for? And you can also [upload you blend file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)